# Eigenspace definition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is the definition I have for *eigenspace*:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A \in Mn(\mathbb C)$. Then

{$v \in \mathbb C^n|Av= \lambda v$}$=W_\lambda$

is a subspace of $\mathbb C^n$, called the *eigenspace* associated to $\lambda$.

The proof shows that $(0,0,.....,0)$ is in $W_\lambda$. But isn't an eigenvector supposed to be nonzero? How then is $(0,0,....,0)$ in $W_\lambda$?

Or maybe this definition is incomplete, and an eigenspace contains the zero vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ is by definition the solution space of $A-\lambda I$, and hence it always contains the zero vector. The eigenvector/s corresponding to $\lambda$ are the non-zero vectors from the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: So is the definition above accurate?

Comment: The definition above is almost accurate. The eigenspace includes all such nonzero $v$ as described, plus the zero vector. You have to throw it in there explicitly to avoid cases as you have described.

Comment: I guess you can say the definition is accurate: you just need to allow the zero vector to also be in the space even though it is not an eigenvector.

Comment: Yes $Av=\lambda v$ if and only if $(A-\lambda I)v=0$.

Comment: @Vladhagen and Any Thank you for your help